# How to change/remove BIOS splash screen on Lenovo B460e laptop?

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I got a Lenovo B460e laptop yesterday (given by the Tamil Nadu (India) Govt).

It has Windows 7 Professional preinstalled.

The BIOS has a funny looking flash screen. Is there a way to get rid of it or change it?

Comment: If there is a way it will be in the bios to disable the lenovo splash screen, it may not be called that in the bios.

Comment: Your user guides can be found on this page....http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/guides-and-manuals/detail.page?&DocID=UM010925

Comment: You can change the BIOS Splash image. Instructions [here](http://deezthomas.com/9-tutorials/20-tutorial-change-bios-splash-on-lenovo-b460e-tn-govt-laptop.html?showall=1&limitstart=).

Answer (score 3):

Change it?  Very doubtful.  Also, as a government IT guy, i would recommend you leave the bios of a computer of that nature alone.  I doubt your IT team would like you to go poking around with it.  Sorry if this doesnt help.

In that vein, the only change that you will most likely be able to do with a business class laptop, is to remove the bios screen itself, and go straight to the verbose style post screen (shows the memory count, bios version, boot status, etc.)

Comment: Its not really a govt. laptop. Its been given away: distributed for free by the govt

Comment: @Akash,  Thats pretty cool actually.  Good on the government for doing that.  I would however still stick with "dont mess with it" if at all possible.  To my knowledge, like I said, the only change you could do to the bios screen would be to go back to the verbose post screen, and skip the "title screen" as it were.

Be happy with a free laptop...

Answer (score 1):

Generally OEM manufactured desktops and laptops won't provide a utility to replace the splash screen, but this isn't uncommon with standalone motherboards that one would use when building a PC.

It's possible to modify and reflash most BIOSes but you need to know exactly what you are doing otherwise you risk an unbootable system.  Mods are out there but it's very risky to attempt any of this.

OEMs generally purchase a BIOS toolkit from a BIOS provider (Phoenix, etc.) and then use said tools to customize the BIOS.  It may be possible to acquire such utilities (probably not legally) but it is equally as risky as above.